# JQueryMobile not working properly with PhoneGap

Tags: jquery-mobile

First of all I have seen every single question stating the same issue on Stack and non of them applied to mine

I was building my First PhoneGap App and i want to use jQueryMobile libraries 
anyways, the JQuery Styles is not working properly,

My Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">btn1</a>
                <p>I Am Now A Mobile Developer!!</p>
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline  ui-corner-all">btn2</a>

            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h1>Footer Text</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the results are 
[image]

as you can see the button inline and corner all attributes worked fine but still that is not the expectedP

Comment: check the tutorial  here -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rW0Trnx7Yjo

Comment: can you try `<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">` ?

Comment: @BipBip it's not about the footer position, the style is not applied it's supposed to give a specific colour and look to header and footer

Comment: @Tasos, I did followed the tutorial, same problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You didnt reference them properly
Remove the dot. I following the folder structure of where your css files are, your java script files should be here /js not ./js

So reference like this
[code]
 [/code]